# Unhashing with certutil in batchfile

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, hash, certutil

So I'm learning about hashing in Windows Batchfile and I was wondering if there is a simple way to unhash hashed text.

To hash the text, I have been using this:

```
set /p input=Text: 

echo %input%>%temp%\hashinput.tmp
CertUtil -hashfile %temp%\hashinput.tmp sha256 | findstr /v "hash">%temp%\hashoutput.tmp
set /p output=<%temp%\hashoutput.tmp

del %temp%\hashinput.tmp
del %temp%\hashoutput.tmp

echo %output%
```

All it's doing is sending the user input to a temporary file, hashing it and sending that to a temporary file and setting a variable to the output before removing the files.

After some looking around I, have been unable to find a way to unhash text using CertUtil or any other commands. If there is an easy way I would love to know how.

Comment: What the hell is "unhashing"?? You seem to confuse "hashing" encryption or something. To compute a hash of a file means to generate a fingerprint of that file in order to become able to verify the validity/completeness of the file. You cannot reverse that process to get a file out of a hash. A hash has a certain length (SHA-256 uses 256 bits), independent on the length of the file you derive it from, so a file may contain much more information than the hash (just as an additional argument for why it is irreversible)…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no feasible way to get the original input from the [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), that is the whole point. You can try brute force by trying all possible inputs but that is not practical, it will take way too much time.

Another name for a hash is a [one-way function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function)...